# How to export grouped/nested/tree data from Material-table to CSV?

Tags: reactjs, export-to-csv, material-table

I'm trying to export tree data grouped by some headers to csv, but when I open the spreadsheet only headers are displayed.

```
        <MaterialTable
          title=""
          icons={tableIcons}
          isLoading={dataCompany.load}
          columns={dataCompany.columns}
          options={{
            exportButton: true,
            exportAllData: true,
          }}
          data={dataCompany.companyData}
        />
```

[image: My Material-Table with tree/nested data]
[image: The exported to csv. Only headers.]

Comment: From the picture it looks like all of your row data is in the expansion panel. The expansion panel is not part of the auto generated data. In that case, you should look on overriding the export function

Comment: Yes @Idan this data isn't generate by default. I saw this issue https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/718